# FFMPEG: animation: Zoom In and zoom Out

Tags: ffmpeg, zooming

How can I get the following effect with FFMPEG?

[image]

I know I have to do it with Zoompan, but the truth is, I've been trying for a while and I can not!

Comment: Include what you have tried and how it did fail in your question.

Comment: I tried several methods, based on the following: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526345/ffmpeg-how-to-move-the-video-without-stretching-it) But I did not keep anything, because nothing worked!

Comment: And with respect to the example image that I published: **Why is not the image displayed, instead of the URL?** _I'm relatively new to stackoverflow._

Comment: @Hugo Use the image button instead of using a bare URL. See [Markdown Editing Help: Images](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images), or click the question-mark-in-a-circle icon in the upper right of the editing textbox.

Comment: Thanks @llogan, I was seeing it, now I know how to do it, I only need 10 reputation points, to post images: _You need at least 10 reputation to post images_

Comment: Didn't know about the rep limitation.

Answer (score 3):

the following code works:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i imagen.png -vf "scale=iw*4:ih*4,zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,60),30),zoom+0.002,zoom-0.002)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom)/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom)/2':d=25*5" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "1280x720" out.mp4 -y`

The code is based on the following (answered by Gyan):
[FFMPEG How to zoom in and then zoom out in one command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460983/ffmpeg-how-to-zoom-in-and-then-zoom-out-in-one-command-line).

**Also, if there is a way to do it better, I invite you to participate.**

Answer (score 1):

Please try following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i image.jpg \
       -vf zoompan=d=300:z='if(gte(zoom,1.8)+eq(ld(1),1)*gt(zoom,1),zoom-0.03*st(1,1),zoom+0.03+0*st(1,0)):x=iw/2-(iw/zoom/2):y=ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)' \
       -t 10 output.mp4
```

The code is based on the following:

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/ffmpeg-zoompan-in-and-out-alternately/23653#23653

Comment: Thank you. But it works badly with the latest version of FFMPEG. Did you try it before posting the code?

Comment: Yes, but i am using older version. so, this code work fine. @Hugo